# Sample code to create a simple form in honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am an expereinced Java developer but very new to android programming.  I am working on a project for one of my clients who wants to create an android application out of a site survey they have been doing by hand (pen and paper).

What I'm looking to do is create a UI mach up to present as a possible solution.  I have looked around but cannot find any sample code to create a simple form.

What I want to do:

I want to have a form (that ideally kinda looks like the way mail looks when you are creating a new message) that allows the user to fill out Name, Address, Business Name, etc.  As well a as some custom drop downs, buttons, etc.

I want to do this for a tablet pc so I'm targeting Honeycomb 3.x as my platform.

Can someone point me to any sample code to get me started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by reading some layout tutorials such as this one: http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/, or the Android developer docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html.

All of the objects you require can be implemented as views in your layout.

Comment: Awesome, that first link to the tutorial was just what I was looking for, thanks!